# Get channels of category discord v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to get all channels and delete these channels of category in discord v14, but throw me an error:

> client.channels.cache.get(...).children.forEach is not a function

```
client.channels.cache.get("1234567890123456")
    .children.forEach(channel => {
       channel.delete();
     })

// client.channels.cache.get("1234567890123456")  Works but didn't give me the channels.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CategoryChannel.children` is type `CategoryChannelChildManager`, which doesn't have a `forEach` method, so you can't call `forEach` on it. `CategoryChannelChildManager.cache` is type `Collection<Snowflake, GuildChannel>`, which does has a `forEach` method, so you can call `forEach` on it.

```js
client.channels.cache.get("1234567890123456")
    .children.cache.forEach([channelId, channel]=> {
       channel.delete();
     })
```